# Extract date from string and format yyyy-mm-dd in vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, vba, date, format

I'm trying to convert existing vba code into vb.net code.

The purpose is to extract the date from a string and then to format it into mySql style.

My working vba code is:

```
mData = Format(Left(Trim(Eventi(NuoviEv).innertext), 10), "yyyy-mm-dd")
```

In vb.net I was able to use the following to extract the date; but I wasn't able to format it.

```
mData = eventi(nuoviev).innertext.substring(0,10).trim()
```

How can I add formatting for "yyyy-mm-dd" onto the vb.net code?

An example of string (value of 'Eventi(NuoviEv).innertext') is:

```
03/12/2014 - Something happens
```

Is it a waste of resources if I use this?:

```
mData = Eventi(NuoviEv).innertext.substring(6, 4) & "-" & _ 
    Eventi(NuoviEv).innertext.substring(3, 2) & "-" & _ 
    Eventi(NuoviEv).innertext.substring(0, 2)
```

Thanks to MAC I also got this solution:

```
mData = Date.ParseExact(eventi(nuoviev).innertext.substring(0,10), "dd/mm/yyyy", nothing).tostring("yyyy-mm-dd")
```

Only a doubt: it seems a little complex, isn't there a simpler  way?
However, can you indicate the better solution?

Comment: Can you add some sample strings you are trying to evaluate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways but I'm gonna answer it in the most simple way so this is easier to apply. Try this...

```
stringFormattedDate = CDate(stringNotFormattedDate).toString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

If this solves your problem, please let me know down to the comments below.
If there are errors, please raise it too but it works fine for me.

The reason why I added `CDate` is to convert `string` date to type `date` in order for me to format it using `.toString()` which returns your string date back to another string date that is formatted like your MySQL format

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't solve but your answer makes me understand the way. This works: `mData = Date.ParseExact(eventi(nuoviev).innertext.substring(0,10), "dd/mm/yyyy", System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo).tostring("yyyy-mm-dd")` Only a doubt: it seems a little complex, isn't there a simpler  way?

Comment: let me clarify.. you are trying to parse the date from a date/time string and the string comes from where again?

Comment: I need to extract date in italian style and convert it to SQL style

Comment: can you comment here the format of the "italian style" that you meant?

Comment: I gave an example of the original string: "03/12/2014 - something happens" where date is december 03 2014 and I need a string in SQL style: "2014-12-03".  I hope is clear now

Comment: oh my bad... so your input is "03/12/2014" and you want it to be converted to "2014-12-03" am I correct?

Comment: how about this...try it CDate(Eventi(NuoviEv).innertext).toString("yyyy-MM-dd"). I think that would work if Eventi(NuoviEv).innertext is a String and you're using VB.Net...

Comment: It doesn't work ... I think because of date format ... you can test it on .net fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76979/discussion-between-mac-and-genespos).

Answer (score 1):

use this `Date.ParseExact` or `Date.TryParseExact` with correct format string.

```
 Dim dt As Date = Date.ParseExact(mData, "yyyy-mm-dd", 
            System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)
```

or

```
Dim format() = {"yyyy-mm-dd", "d/M/yyyy", "dd-MM-yyyy"}
 Dim dt As Date = Date.ParseExact(mData, format,  
     System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, 
     Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None)
```

hope it helps.for more details  [DateTime.ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044(v=VS.90).aspx) and [DateTime.TryParseExact Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044(v=VS.90).aspx)

**update**

from the above code,you have successfully extracted the date and stored it to the variable `mdata`.now our next task is to convert the `string` to `datetime`,for which we can use two inbuilt vb functions as mentioned above  [DateTime.ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044(v=VS.90).aspx) and [DateTime.TryParseExact Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044(v=VS.90).aspx).you can easily understand code behind the functions if you go thorugh the links.both of these function converts the string values supplied to it as first parameter to datetime and to custom format we specify as second parameter.

Comment: I'm new to vb.net ... can you explain a little bit more? I'm not able to apply it to my code

Comment: I was asking myself: why use a date object? Is the only way? I need just a string (I prefer a string for updating the Database)

Comment: it depends upon you to use it as string or date type.i was just giving answer to your question in stackoverflow not in your mind.

Comment: Sorry, I did not mean to be rude. I was just saying that my code vba returned a string

Comment: see,its not about bieng rude or something,be Specific while asking questions else your question will be useless and time spent by fellow programmers also become wasted.

Comment: I'm trying your code but I get an error: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime value" (translated)

Answer (score 1):

Just

```
strValue = Strings.Format(Now(), "yyyy-MM-dd")
```

will do