# Detailed Steps For Read Date From Excel and How to Set Or Write in Google Form Datepiker (DateField) in UiPath?

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio

I need detailed step by step Automation for read the date(dd/MM/yyy) from the excel and write or set in Google form date field.

in excel Date was stored in dd/MM/yyyy(01/03/1996) formate.

i didn't get how to get and write in google form date field.

Comment: You are asking for a literal solution for your project. It would be better if you try yourself first and then come to us with failed/not working solution. If you are completely new to UiPath then I would suggest you to complete UiPath Foundation course here https://academy.uipath.com

Comment: Use ParseExact, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30034641/extract-date-from-string-and-format-yyyy-mm-dd-in-vb-net

Comment: Thank You @GubbaNubNub For your answer but I trying then after I wrote this question.

Comment: That is great! but it will be more helpful if you tell us what you tried so far and what is not working. Like TypeInto or Set Text activity throwing error or something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use datatable for the excel which consist of date ... if the date format is fixed you can just write it with string