# How can I handle (set/write) the datepicker from Google Form in UiPath?

Tags: javascript, datepicker, uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-activity

I can't handle in a simple way the datepicker of [this test google form](https://forms.gle/qMwRMUed78inNEBh6) with UiPath Studio. The steps I tried are detailed further below.

I really thought someone had the same problem since it's a widely spread service. [Ok there's this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76373084/detailed-steps-for-read-date-from-excel-and-how-to-set-or-write-in-google-form-d), but still.

I tried :

- the 'Type into' activity
- the 'set text' activity
- the 'set web attribute' activity
- the 'Keyboard Shortcut' activity

I really tried to inspect and look for the right selector but well it's not that easy for this one I guess.

I'm not qualified in it but UiPath (the automation software) is able of [injecting JavaScript](https://docs.uipath.com/fr/activities/other/latest/ui-automation/inject-js-script).

I expect a quick method that would input a date in [the test google form](https://forms.gle/qMwRMUed78inNEBh6).

If you have any idea, I'll take it for sure !

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you have tested or if I got you wrong, but it instantly works with a `Type Into`:

[image]

and

[image]

with selectors:

[image]

Comment: Hello !

I have been testing it for weeks like you can't imagine.
I modified a lot of properties.

For instance, the only difference I had with your selector is the ticking for "Responsive website".

I had errors like "Impossible to find UI element" with a NodeNotFound Exception.

I've finally disabled the Computer Vision and the Selector... to activate what ? THE IMAGE recognition.

I thought it was a clunky and unreliable method but it works perfectly.
I'm a bit disappointed about the others. I even tried a click inside to underline the 'dd' field. It didn't work neither.

Comment: By the way, The simulate input doesn't work neither even with the image selection. Only the "hardware/keyboard event".

Also I would like to thank you for the try because it guides me saying that there might be another problem somewhere.

I'm currently using an Google Chrome extension of UiPath (9.0.6827) with the 2023.10.0 UiPath version. Do you have the same Google Chrome extension ?

Thank you very much once again !

Comment: My Chrome UiPath is 23.10.1. Well did you try to let Studio create the activity via App Recorder? Or did you create manually?

Comment: Yes I do it manually. I never use the App recorder. Maybe I should. What's your opinion ?
Is it better ?

Comment: Sure, App recorder is for making sure it works. Afterwards go for some edits. Often the selectors are not proper. But for simple testing, do always the recorder.